# How to manage 40Mb data in okhttp response body efficiently?

Tags: performance, rest, httpclient, response, okhttp

I am getting a 40MB data in the okhttp response. and its taking more than 25 sec responseStr = response.body().string() to process. Can any one help me to reduce the processing time.
[full source code](https://javabelazy.blogspot.com/2018/08/how-to-use-xml-x-www-form-urlencoded.html)

Comment: 40 Megabits (40Mb) or 40 Megabytes (40MB)?

Comment: its 40MB (Megabytes)

Comment: Have you considered *not* loading a 40MB response into a string?

Comment: is that make any difference?